# SQL QUERY TO Transform columns

Tags: sql

I have a database with 3 Columns (TS -Timestamp , NM=Name and VL=Value) like this

[image]

For further downstream processing, I need 1 Row for each Timestamp and Values as 3 columns .Column name being paramter1 parameter2 and parmeter3

The number of parameters' could vary and cannot be hard coded
how should the sql query be framed for this

Any help is appreciated
THanks

Comment: Tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation as a general structure:

```
select ts,
       max(case when nm = 'parameter1' then vl end) as parameter1,
       max(case when nm = 'parameter2' then vl end) as parameter2,
       max(case when nm = 'parameter3' then vl end) as parameter3
from t
group by ts
```

If you need this to handle an unknown level of parameters, then you need dynamic SQL -- that is, to construct the SQL as a string and then execute it.  You can do this using a scripting language in the database or using an application.  However, what you do exactly depends on the database you are using.